# Traduire « shall » et « must » en préservant la formulation : choix et temps de verbe ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, verbes, temps-grammatical, formulation

> Every time the device is used it [*shall*](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/shall) be inspected. The device
> [*must*](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/must) not be used with objects weighing more than 500g. [[Traduction Google](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=Every%20time%20the%20device%20is%20used%20it%20shall%20be%20inspected.%20The%20device%20must%20not%20be%20used%20with%20objects%20weighing%20more%20than%20500g.&op=translate) : *Chaque fois que l'appareil est utilisé, il doit être inspecté. L'appareil ne doit pas être utilisé avec des objets pesant plus de 500 g.*]

Il s'agit d'une obligation dans ces deux phrases à la voix passive.

Dans un contexte de symétrie procédurale où l'on veut traduire en français et coller le plus fidèlement possible à la formulation originale en langue anglaise (ordre des mots, voix etc.), pense-t-on utiliser le même verbe (*devoir*) et le même temps (comme dans la traduction de *Google*) ? **Pourquoi ?**

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145836/discussion-on-question-by-user32457-traduire--shall--et--must--en-preservant); please do not continue the discussion here.** [Remainder of this template removed by hand afterwards because it's so frightfully condescending.]

Comment: @user32457 il faut plus de contexte pour analyser l'original et trouver la traduction la plus juste : quel est cet appareil ? Dans quel cadre est-il utilisé ? Qui sont l'émetteur et le récepteur du message et quel est le support de communication ? Qu'entend-on par *inspect* ? ...

Answer (score 3):

Dans ces exemples précis *shall* et *must* expriment tous les deux une obligation. *Shall* exprime plutôt une obligation formelle (très employé dans le domaine juridique par exemple, et aussi dans le contexte d'énonciation de règlement), *must* est plus du ressort de la morale. Le français a bien des façons d'exprimer l'obligation si on ne veut pas répéter « devoir » : **il faut**, **il est nécessaire**, **avoir l'obligation de**, **il est indispensable de**, etc.

Ce qui me gêne le plus dans la traduction de google ce n'est pas la répétition de « devoir » mais l'emploi du passif (et je viens de voir que DeepL ne fait pas mieux dans ce cet exemple). Le passif est beaucoup plus employé en anglais qu'en français<sup>1</sup>. Ici on sent l'anglais qui se cache derrière la traduction.

Autre élément que je modifierais dans la phrase proposée par google c'est la traduction de *inspect*. Ce n'est pas vraiment un faux sens, « inspecter » est aussi employé en français dans le sens d'« examiner avec minutie », mais personnellement ce n'est pas le verbe que j’emploierais dans ce qui semble être une notice d'utilisation. Je préfèrerais « vérifier » ou plutôt « contrôler » comme proposé par certains dictionnaires<sup>2</sup>.

On pourrait suggérer ces traductions :

- Il est nécessaire (ou « il est indispensable » s'il y a risque de danger) de bien vérifier l'appareil à chaque utilisation.
- On ne doit pas (il ne faut pas) utiliser l'appareil avec des objets pesant plus de 500 g.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Voir [ce cours](https://www.letudiant.fr/boite-a-docs/document/la-forme-passive-0907.html) par exemple.</sup> 
 <sup><sup>2</sup> [Par exemple](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-french/inspect).</sup>

Comment: Autre synonyme : "il est impératif de"

Answer (score 0):

L'appareil sera inspecté à chaque utilisation.

L'appareil ne doit pas être utilisé avec des objets pesant plus de 500g.

Comment: Pourquoi choisit-on le futur dans la première phrase ? Pourquoi pas le présent ? Dans un même texte où l'on a les deux phrases l'une à la suite de l'autre, pense-t-on que d'avoir le futur dans l'une et le présent dans l'autre change la lecture ou la compréhension des obligations ?

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t j'aime assez le futur ici. Il est très utilisé en français dans les directives, règlements et notices, où l'équivalent naturel est *shall*. *You shall not kill* -> "tu ne tueras point".

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t Je suis en total désaccord avec cet article sur l'utilisation du futur associé au passif, en particulier sur le fait que le futur prête à équivoque.

Comment: (ou du moins, davantage à équivoque en français qu'en anglais, surtout avec le verbe *inspect* ici)

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t comme je l'ai dit, la réponse de Bazin me parait satisfaisante en l'état (pourquoi le downvote d'ailleurs ?). On pourrait l'améliorer si l'OP fournissait plus de contexte.

Comment: L'idée du site est aussi d'appuyer des réponses qui nous paraissent justes en cliquant sur +1 :) Et d'y apporter des compléments ou arguments supplémentaires en commentant. En l'occurrence, "L'appareil sera inspecté à chaque utilisation" me parait bien mieux formulé que "Chaque fois que l'appareil est utilisé, il doit être inspecté".

Comment: @guillaume31 Je crois qu'il existe une différence entre ce site et FB/Twitter. Les commentaires ne sont qu'un écho. Ils ne permettent pas de faire remonter la question en tête de liste de la vue active et d'attiser la consultation et l'ajout de nouvelles réponses etc. Mais on est libre de rester dans l'ombre du commentaire !

Comment: ... surtout quand le commentaire permet de préciser une petite chose ou deux, au lieu de réécrire entièrement une réponse qui est au mieux légère variante d'une reponse déja donnée ;)